# Extract element within string into nested list

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am working on a routing project. The route looks like this `"CNSHG(B)-PAMIT(R)-COCTG(B)-USHOU(R)-COCTG(B)-USMSY"` and I want to break it into a nested list. Also, a route contains multiple segments for example CNSHG-PAMIT is one segment transported using B and then PAMIT-COCTG transported using R i.e, Rail, and so on.

Input:

```
"CNSHG(B)-PAMIT(R)-COCTG(B)-USHOU(R)-COCTG(B)-USMSY"
```

The output should be like this:

```
[[CNSHG, PAMIT, B],[PAMIT, COCTG, R],[COCTG, USHOU, B],[USHOU, COCTG, R],[COCTG, USMSY, B]]
```

I have tried using regex and the below codes but it didn't work.

```
route.str.extract('(.)\s\((.\d+)')
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why are you using `(.\d+)`? There are no digits in your input.

Comment: Also, your final destination `USMSY` doesn't have a means of transportation following it (`B`, `R`, or something else). Will that always be the case?

Comment: @MattDMo The transport mode is written in brackets with the first transport port, so there is no mode on the last port because that is the destination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':["CNSHG(B)-PAMIT(R)-COCTG(B)-USHOU(R)-COCTG(B)-USMSY"]})
df['result'] = df['col'].str.findall(r'(\w+)\((?=[^()]*\)-(\w+))([^()]*)\)')
```

Output of `df['result']`:

```
[('CNSHG', 'PAMIT', 'B'), ('PAMIT', 'COCTG', 'R'), ('COCTG', 'USHOU', 'B'), ('USHOU', 'COCTG', 'R'), ('COCTG', 'USMSY', 'B')]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bWE5ey/1). *Details*:

- `(\w+)` - one or more word chars
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `(?=[^()]*\)-(\w+))` - a positive lookahead that requires (immediately to the right of the current location):

  - `[^()]*` - zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`
  - `\)-` - a `)-` string
  - `(\w+)` - Group 2: one or more word chars
- `([^()]*)` - Group 3: zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a `)` char.